# Mutate across multiple variables, using a list of third variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to obtain values of a list of grades (math, language, sci, etc.) conditional on the presence of valid values in 2016 (`validity_2016`=="yes"), into a new variable called `grades_{subjects}` (eg. grades_math).

```
df<-tibble(person = c("Alice", "Bob", "Mary"),
           validity_2016 = c(NA, "yes", NA),
           likes_ham = c("no", "yes", "yes"),
           grades_math_2015=c(6,2,4),
           grades_math_2016=c(3,5,7),
           grades_language_2015=c(7,1,9),
           grades_language_2016=c(3,6,7),
           grades_sci_2015=c(7,1,9),
           grades_sci_2016=c(3,6,7))
```

I was wondering the viability to use `dplyr`'s `mutate_at` or `mutate(across`, in the following way:

```
dplyr::mutate(across(grades_math_2016, grades_language_2016,grades_sci_2016),
~dplyr::case_when(!is.na(validity_2016)~list(grades_math_2015,grades_language_2015,grades_sci_2015)~.),
.names="{col}"))
```

The outcomes should look like this:

```
df<-tibble(person = c("Alice", "Bob", "Mary"),
               validity_2016 = c(NA, "yes", NA),
               likes_ham = c("no", "yes", "yes"),
               grades_math_2015=c(6,2,4),
               grades_math_2016=c(3,5,7),
               grades_language_2015=c(7,1,9),
               grades_language_2016=c(3,6,7),
               grades_sci_2015=c(7,1,9),
               grades_sci_2016=c(3,6,7),
               grades_math=c(6,5,4),
               grades_language=c(7,6,7),
               grades_sci=c(7,6,9))
```

Comment: Hello Andres, is it possible for you to reduce the columns? The more simple the question , the faster we can answer.

Comment: In fact, my real problem is with a dataset of around 109 variables, that is not possible for me to reduce the columns, because i would loose the background of the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using a `mutate` and `ifelse` for each subject. Something like:

```r
df2 = df %>%
  mutate(grades_math = ifelse(validatiy_2016 == "yes", grades_math_2016, grades_math_2015))
```

The downside if this approach is you need to repeat it for each subject. This could be automated with something like:

```r
out_cols = c("grades_math", "grades_sci")

for(col in out_cols){
  c15 = paste0(col,"_2015")
  c16 = paste0(col,"_2016")
  df = df %>% mutate(!!sym(col) := ifelse(validaity_2016 == "yes", !!sym(c16), !!sym(c15)))
}
```

Where `!!sym(x)` takes the text saved in the variable `x` and turns it into a variable name (e.g. if `x = "sci"` then `!!sym(x)` gives us the variable `sci` instead of the text `"sci"` or the variable `x`).

Answer (score 2):

## `tidyverse` and `rlang` example:

This example uses `mutate` and `case_when` to assign the variables as you described.  I wrapped it in a function in case this is something you would do often.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

make_grade_columns <- function(df, condition_col, year_view){
  year_column_names <- colnames(df)[str_detect(colnames(df), year_view) & colnames(df) != condition_col & !str_detect(colnames(df), "validity")]
  year_prior_column_names <- colnames(df)[str_detect(colnames(df), as.character(as.numeric(year_view) - 1)) & colnames(df) != condition_col]
  return_col_names <- str_remove(year_column_names, "_\\d\\d\\d\\d")
  df <- df  %>% mutate(
    !!return_col_names[1] := case_when(
      (df %>% select(!!!condition_col)) == "yes" ~ !! sym(year_column_names[1]),
                                               T ~ !! sym(year_prior_column_names[1])),
    !!return_col_names[2] := case_when(
      (df %>% select(!!!condition_col)) == "yes" ~ !! sym(year_column_names[2]),
                                               T ~ !! sym(year_prior_column_names[2])),
    !!return_col_names[3] := case_when(
      (df %>% select(!!!condition_col)) == "yes" ~ !! sym(year_column_names[3]),
                                               T ~ !! sym(year_prior_column_names[3])))
  
  return(df)
}

make_grade_columns(df, "validity_2016", "2016") %>% 
 select(person, validity_2016, grades_math, grades_sci, grades_language) 

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# person validity_2016    grades_math   grades_sci   grades_language
# <chr>  <chr>                  <dbl>      <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1 Alice  NA                      6          7               7
# 2 Bob    yes                     5          6               6
# 3 Mary   NA                      4          9               9
```

Suppose you changed it up and wanted to see the grades on the IF they answer "yes" to `likes_ham`.  Simply have that as your conditioning column for the function.

```
make_grade_columns(df, "likes_ham", "2016")%>% 
  select(person, likes_ham, grades_math, grades_sci, grades_language) 
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# person likes_ham    grades_math grades_sci grades_language
# <chr>  <chr>              <dbl>      <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1 Alice  no                  6          7               7
# 2 Bob    yes                 5          6               6
# 3 Mary   yes                 7          7               7
```

The function will take the yes answer and return the values from the year.  If the answer is "no" then it will return the value from the year prior instead.

Comment: Good answer. I think is not so flexible like the following, because you have to specify the parameters in mutate for each variable (`col_names[1:200]`)

Comment: With regards to the brackets from return_col_names? Yeah.  I could make it more flexible using a `for loop` if your use case requires.  Let me know the pattern and scaling use case and I can change the code.  Additionally, this function will bark at you if you try using a year that does not have a prior year available.

Additionally, using #s in colnames (like the validity_2016) will return nonsense for any column not named validity (not including the `grades` columns).